# Error when Uploading Theme in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, ini

I am trying to upload the Divi theme on the Ricky server with helio host, and I get an error that says `The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.' I looked in the wp-admin folder on my server and did not see the php.ini file, so I created one and added this code:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

This did not seem to help as I kept getting the same error message. I tried installing the plugin "Upload Max File Size" but it did not seem to help either. I read through some blog post, and forum discussions but could still not seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Noah

Comment: php.ini is hardly ever available on shared hosting, if that is what you have. You can change the setting within wp-admin, or wpconfig.sys, or use FTP to upload the theme files.

Comment: @RST, yeah it is. Where should I change it within wp-admin? And if I used FTP to upload theme files, what directory would I upload it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php.ini file is the main configuration file for php. It is not located in the wp-admin folder. If you have a vps you can looking the location of that file with a php_info(), else you have to ask to your provider.
If you can't edit your php.ini file, you can :

- use the [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function
- upload the theme with ftp

[Php.ini doc page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102744/error-when-uploading-theme-in-wordpress)

Comment: I contacted the hosting company, and they increased the file size, now it is working. Thanks so much :D.